# How can I add this function to a Result Value off a Subroutine shown above

Tags: vba, function, rounding

Need to round up the value in cell A10 to the nearest 5.
I think I`ve got the function right just not sure how to add it to the sub above.
I think perhaps the Function LWhole value should be the value from the result of the sub above is that right?
Or should I do away with the function in which case how could I round it up or down to the nearest 5

```
       Private Sub Toolpod_Width_Click()
    
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker.xlsm")
    
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Job Card Master")
    
        Dim BodyLength As Range
        Set BodyLength = ws.Range("A10")
        
        Select Case Toolpod_Width.Value
        
        Case ("600")
            BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 680
         
        Case ("800")
            BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 880
        
        Case ("900")
            BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 980
        
        Case ("1000")
            BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 1080
        End Select
        
        
     
         
        Toolpod_Width.Value = "Toolpod Width"
        
        Toolpod_Width.Visible = False
        End Sub

     Function CustomRound(pValue As Double) As Double
        
        LWhole = Int(pValue)
        
        LFraction = pValue - LWhole
        
        If LFraction < 5 Then
        CustomRound = LWhole
        
        Else
        
        CustomRound = LWhole + 5
        
        End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `BodyLength.Value = CustomRound(BodyLength.Value)` ?

Comment: Would you declare customround as a variable

Comment: I don't understand your question. `CustomRound` is your *function*. It expects a number (Double) as parameter, does some magic (havn't had a look to it) and returns a number. I assume that you want to round the number of the cell you named `BodyLength`. What do you want with a variable? And even if, don't name it like the function.

Comment: All works fine just ignore the above just me being stupid. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Public Function CustomRound(pValue As Double) As Double
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        CustomRound = .MRound(pValue, 5)
    End With
End Function
```